# Add key-value pair in Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object in Javascript. I want to add key-value pair in it.

```
var data = {
  Country1: '20',
  country2: '30',
  country3: '40',
  country4: '45'
};
```

It should look like,

```
var data = {
  {name: 'country1', values: '20'},
  {name: 'country2', values: '30'},
  {name: 'country3', values: '40'},
  {name: 'country4', values: '45'},
};
```

I am looking for a solution where from a given object, country names will automatically fall into `name` and values into `values`

Comment: use `Array.map()` function. Such questions were asked many times on SO

Comment: how do you grant the order of the keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate the [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the object with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and return an object in the format that you want.

Note: to ensure the order of the objects, you can sort the keys using String#localeCompare with the `numeric: true` option.

```js
var data = {
    'Country1' : '20',
    'country2': '30',
    'country3': '40',
    'country4' : '45'
};

var result = Object.keys(data)
  .sort(function(a, b) { // if you need to ensure the order of the keys
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true})
  })
  .map(function(key) {
    return {
      name: key,
      value: data[key]
    };
  });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Objecy.Keys** and **`forEach`** to loop through the Objects,

```js
var data = {
    'Country1' : '20',
    'country2': '30',
    'country3': '40',
    'country4' : '45'
};
var result = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    result.push({'name':key,'value':data[key]});
    
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There's `Array.prototype.map()` for this exact case.

Answer (score 0):

or use `Object.entries` :

```
 data = Object.entries(data).map(([name, values]) => ({name, values}));
```

Comment: Could you update your answer and explain what you are doing. Many thanks in advance

Comment: @mzaragoza i just convert the returned 2darray into an array of objects using array destructuring and ES2015 object literals.