# Modify object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert object

```
var data = {"USD": 12323,"CAD":32123}
```

to become

```
[{"id":"USD","value":12323},{"id":"CAD","value":32123}]
```

This is what i tried so far

```
var res = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { 
    return [k, result[k]];
});
```

and get the result

```
[["USD", 12323],["CAD", 32123]]
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of this: `return [k, result[k]]` do `return { id: k, value: result[k] }`

Comment: @gurvinder372 I dont think so. I haven't looked for it actually. Just that I like to make answers a bit descriptive. So for such cases, I prefer comments. Will try to answer instead from next time. Thanks for asking. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952992/add-key-value-pair-in-javascript-object/47953074#47953074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating one array, not an object. Change `[]` to `{}`:

```js
var res = {"USD": 12323,"CAD":32123};

res = Object.keys(res).map(function(k) { 
    return {id: k, value:res[k]};
});

console.log(res);
```

as an alternative, you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var res = {"USD": 12323,"CAD":32123};

res = Object.keys(res).map(x => x = { id: x, value: res[x]});

console.log(res);
```

or [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
var res = {"USD": 12323,"CAD":32123};

var resWArrow = Object.entries(res).map(function(k) { 
    return {id: k[0], value: k[1]};
});

console.log('Without arrow: ' + JSON.stringify(resWArrow));

var resArrow = Object.entries(res).map(x => x = { id: x[0], value: x[1] });

console.log('With arrow: ' + JSON.stringify(resArrow));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your `return` statement to

```
return {id: k, value:result[k]}; //observe that an object is returned instead of an array
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = {"USD": 12323,"CAD":32123};
var res = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { 
   return {id: k, value:data[k]};
});
console.log( res );
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could take [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the elements and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the result.

```js
var data = { "USD": 12323, "CAD": 32123 },
    result = Object.entries(data).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys of the object and map them like follows:

```
Object.keys(res).map(function(key) { 
    return {id: key, value: data[key]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return statement and return an object

```js
var res = {
  "USD": 12323,
  "CAD": 32123
}
var m = Object.keys(res).map(function(item) {
  return {
    id: item,
    value: res[item]
  }

})
console.log(m)
```